# How do you say "feed on (something)" in Latin

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax

Not the most experienced in Latin, so this may seem redundant to most, but I'm trying to figure out how to say "to feed on (something)". I'm assuming I just change the case of the object with the verb *alo/alere*, but I'm not 100% sure which case to use and if i should be using a preposition. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Indeed the passive voice of *alo* with the abl. case can mean what you are aiming for. [in L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=alo):

> Hence in pass. with the abl. = vesci, to be nourished or sustained with or by something, to live or feed upon.

It gives classical examples, and this example from the Vulgate (Ex. 16:35):

> "... hoc cibo aliti sunt ..."

---

**Another suggestion:**

The 4th dec. noun **victus** means nourishment, provision, diet, etc. and can be adapted to convey the meaning of "feed on".

The medieval story *Navigatio Sancti Brendani* (The voyage of st. Brendanus) is fond of using this word, and we find there:

> Nonagenarius enim sum in hac insula, et triginta annis **in victu piscium**, et sexaginta **in victu illius fontis** (I'm 90 on this island, 30 years I feed on fish, 60 on that fountain.)

Above the suggestion is *sum in victu + (gen.)* to mean *I feed on something*. For now I could not attest this usage in classical sources, but we read in Caesar:

> maiorque pars eōrum **vīctūs in lacte, cāseō, carne cōnsistit**. (and a greater part of their diet consists of milk, cheese and meat.)

Here *consisto* applies to *pars*, but I can't see a reason to reject a general usage: *victus (alicuius) in (+abl.) consistit*.

Comment: *(de)pasco* is another similar verb often used for animals